# Cannot install Pip for a fresh Python 3.2 installation "No matching distribution found for pip<8"

Tags: pip, python-3.2

I created a fresh Python 3.2.2 installation on Windows 10.

I got `get_pip.py` from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.2/

I ran: `C:\Python32\python.exe get-pip.py`

My output:

```
Collecting pip<8 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<8 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip<8
```

I have other versions of Python and Pip installed. What am I missing?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the motivation for using such an old version of python?

Comment: I need to use ChemScript20 (a python interface for chemdraw, which is a chemistry specific program). It runs only on python 2.6 2.7 3.1 and 3.2

Comment: ah ok, appreciate the answer

Comment: I have the same problem for the same reason. I can use Chemscript with the python 3.2.2 that the chemoffice installer makes but I cannot get that to work in R/reticulate/anaconda/virtualenv(pip)

Comment: Even if there was a way to install an old version of Pip in Python 3.2 (which there actually is), that Pip installation would not actually work. It wouldn't be able to install packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.org) as it would fail to find the correct URLs. And there are very few packages on PyPI anyway that would work with Python 3.2. These select few, you may as well install manually, from source.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.2/
Use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/

The problem is because you are using an older version of pip.

Comment: That changed the error to
```File "c:\users\my_name\appdata\local\temp\tmp5_flww\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 131
    phases = (u"\U0001F539", u"\U0001F537", u"\U0001F535")  # type: Any```
Cannot comment full error because maximum characters.

Comment: Cannot find a solution. You better change your python version.

Comment: This is not working because Python 3.5 added new syntax, and Pip just wanted to use it on Python 3.5-compatible releases. But Python 3.2 can't use that.